# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar esta imagen en Python?

Tags: python, pycharm

[[image: ][1]]

Quiero mostrar la imagen anterior usando Python. Soy novata.

Comment: para poder hacer operaciones con la imagen, dentro de codigo, solo pon la ruta de la imagen, ejemplo `C:\\desktop\\images\\ige.png` si quieres mostrarla tendras que usar algunas librerias o modulos de python

Answer (score -2, accepted):

La forma mas simple de mostrar imagen con código.

[image: Mostrar imagen con Matplotlib]

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor, sin contar que una explicación enriquecerá tu aporte, checa [answer]

Answer (score 0):

En Python, sin usar Turtle:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/ejemplo.png')
img.show()
```

Importas `Image` de la librería `PIL`.

Con `Image.open()` abres la imagen cuya dirección le pases por parámetro.

Por último, la muestras con `img.show()`. La imagen se abrirá con el visor de imágenes por defecto.

Por supuesto, tienes que cambiar Angel por tu nombre de usuario del equipo.

——————————————————————————————————————————

Si necesitas usar **Turtle**, ten en cuenta esta limitación: la imagen tiene que ser `.gif` y tu imagen es `.png` (puedes [convertirla](https://imagen.online-convert.com/es/convertir-a-gif))

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

imagen = r"C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/ejemplo.gif"

screen.addshape(imagen)
turtle.shape(imagen)
```